# Xslt: convert child nodes to parent

Tags: xml, xslt, parent-child

I have xml file in which I need to convert child node pair `<verse sID="..." osisID="..."/>` and `<verse eID="..."/>` into parent one

Input file looks like:

```
<verse sID="..." osisID="..."/>
    some xml stuff
<verse eID="..."/>
```

I need it in the following form:

```
<verse sID="..." osisID="...">
    some xml stuff
</verse>
```

I tried different methods. I am able to copy whole file using xsl:copy but the rule for verse does not fire. It gets prority 0.

My xsl is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
 
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" /></xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="osis">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:template>  
  <xsl:template match="osisText">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:template>  
  <xsl:template match="div">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:template>  
  <xsl:template match="chapter">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:template>
  
 <xsl:template match="verse">
    <xsl:text>&lt;verse sID=</xsl:text></xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="@sID"/><xsl:text>&gt;</xsl:text>
 </xsl:template>
 
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: What's the parent element of the text in the input? `<verse/>` is an empty element as it stands. What happend the the attribute `eID`? Are the multiple `verse` elements? Please provide a more complete input.

Comment: Are you limited to XSLT 1? Sounds like a job for `for-each-group select="node()" group-starting-with="verse[@sID and @osisID[">` with a nested `xsl:for-each-group select="current-group()" group-ending-with="verse[@eID]">`. Depending on regularity and consistency of the input it can be rather easy and straightforwards that way.

Comment: The parent of verse element is chapter.

Comment: There are many verse elements.
Attribute  eID can be omitted it is not needed.

Comment: I am limited to XSLT 1 currently.

Comment: your source format seems to be almost the same as the output except "some xml stuff" is now inside the element? and a verse with an eid is gone. Probably best to give us a simple input and the correspoinding output, you can always make the example slightly simpler than your real problem.

Comment: Yes, the difference between input and desired output is in verse element. I would like it to be a parent node with "some xml stuff" as its child/children. Unfortunately "some xml stuff' is too long to be written as a comment.

Comment: I'm finding your example hard to understand. Your first two code blocks are identical, which I assume is a mistake? Can you review your question please? Thanks

Comment: In the source xml both 'verse'' elements are children. I need to change it in a way that 'verse' will be a parent of "some xml stuff". I need to treat each "some xml stuff" as a whole but still discerning it from the previous/next 'verse' element.